# Custom function for Spring ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I'm heavily using Spring to develop an application and I was wondering if there's a way to register custom method which can be used when a bean is defined. Currently I'm using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` to load the bean definitions from a XLM file, then in the XML file I would like to do something like

```
<bean id="bean1" class="..." scope="prototype"
    p:some_property='"hello" + #getCorrelativeNumber()/>
```

Here `some_property` should then be evaluated to `hello0`. I know I can register custom functions using StandardEvaluationContext of SpEL, however I can't figure how to make that work in the context of the `ApplicationContext`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [blog](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language), look at the section which shows to create an application context in which expressions are used to inject values

```
<bean id="engine" class="com.baeldung.spring.spel.Engine">
   <property name="capacity" value="3200"/>
   <property name="horsePower" value="250"/>
   <property name="numberOfCylinders" value="6"/>
</bean>
<bean id="someCar" class="com.baeldung.spring.spel.Car">
   <property name="make" value="Some make"/>
   <property name="model" value="Some model"/>
   <property name="engine" value="#{engine}"/>
   <property name="horsePower" value="#{engine.horsePower}"/>
</bean>
```